# Interchange antisymmetric elements in a matrix

Tags: c, matrix

I am trying to change an element of an array from its position a (not sure if it said so) its antisymmetric position with respect to the center of the matrix, if the position to be exchanged forms part of the center nothing should be done (depending on the Matrix the center can be 1,2 or 4 cells):

```
1  2  3  4  5 
6  7  8  9  10 
11 12 13 14 15 
16 17 18 19 20 
21 22 23 24 25
```

The center would be: 13

An example would be to exchange the number 2 for the number 24. I had thought to do it by calculating the displacements that I have to do in x and y from the center to the position of the element (dx dy), and then the displacements to arrive at the antisymmetric position from The center would be -dx -dy.

```
int mat [][5]={{1,2,3,4,5},{6,7,8,9,10},{11,12,13,14,15},{16,17,18,19,20},{21,22,23,24,25}};
int aux;
int i = 0;
int j = 1;          // i and j are the indeces of the element to be exchanged
int xcenter=col/2;
int ycenter=fil/2;  // xcenter and xcenter are the indeces of the center
int dx = j-xcenter;
int dy = i-ycenter; // dx dy are the displacements
aux=mat[i][j];
mat[i][j]=mat[xcenter-dx][ycenter-dy];
mat[xcenter+dx][ycenter+dy]=aux;
```

My problem comes when the matrix has odd columns or rows, since in that case the center will not be a single position, but it will be a set. For example, this matrix of 5 * 4

```
1  2  3   4
5  6  7   8
9  10 11 12
13 14 15 16
17 18 19 20
```

The Center would be:

```
10 11
```

I do not know find the center, and  from which element of the center to counting displacements.

Comment: Not clear whatr you want to accomplish or if that even is a programming problem.. Just that: it is not a problem of square vs. not square. but odd vs. even number of rows/cols.

Comment: You could also define the centre as some (hypothetical) location half-way between the `10` and `11`  (or at the average location if the "center" is more than two points).

Comment: More significant than the centre is 'would cell containing 2 in the 5*4 (5 rows, 4 columns) matrix move to where 19 is, and vice versa?'  Also, wouldn't the cells containing 10 and 11 need to be swapped?  If not, you need to describe what happens with a 5*7 or 5*8 or 5*9 matrix (and 4*7, 4*8, etc.).  That is, what's the behaviour with more extreme non-square matrices.

Comment: If you have a matrix with `rows` rows and `cols` columns, and an element at row `r` (`r < rows`, `r >= 0`), column `c` (`c < cols`, `c >= 0`), then isn't the antisymmetric element always at row `(rows-1-r)`, column `(cols-1-c)`? There is a "center" cell only when both `rows` and `cols` are odd (at row `r`, `r == rows-r-1`, column `c`, `c == cols-c-1`). In the last example matrix, elements 10 and 11 would be antisymmetric to each other. If they are not, why not?

Comment: yes, you are right. Maybe i did not understand the problem and i have to interchage every element, except when the rows and cols are odd.

Answer (score 0):

You can just simplify your coordinate calculations like this:

```
xcenter-dx = xcenter - (j-xcenter) = 2*xcenter - j = 2*col/2 - j = col - j
```

And likewise

```
xcenter+dx = j
ycenter-dy = fil - i
ycenter+dy = i
```

So you don't have problems with dividing odd numbers by two.